# Making DMA memory temporarily cachable

Tags: c, linux, caching, mmap, dma

I have an arm cortex-a9 quad core device, and I'm programming a multi-process application.
These processes share the same source of input - a DMA buffer which they all access using a mmap() call.

I noticed that the time it takes for the processes to access the DMA memory, is significantly longer than it takes if I change the source of input to be a normal allocated buffer (i.e. allocated using malloc).

I understand why a DMA buffer must be non-cacheable, however, since I have the ability to determine when the buffer is stable (unchanged by the hardware, which is the case most of the time) or dirty (data has changed) I thought I might get a significant speed improvement if I'll make the memory region temporarily cacheable.

Is there a way to do that?

I'm currently using this line to map the memory:

```
void *buf = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED, fd, phy_addr);
```

Thanks!

Comment: DMA buffer is too broad of a definition. How do you obtain/create one?

Comment: I create a DMA buffer with DMA_ALLOC_COHERENT in the device's kernel module.

Comment: you could make memory permanently cacheable, just take care to flush caches before DMA starts and invalidate caches after DMA finishes for each CPU. Drawback is caches operations also take their time. After all memory copying might be faster... If cache-coherence is supported/implemented by cpu/os then manual cache handling could be omitted...

Answer (score 1):

Most modern CPUs use snooping to determine if/when cache lines must be flushed to memory or marked invalid. On such CPUs a "DMA buffer" is identical to a `kmalloc()` buffer. This, of course, assumes the snoop feature works correctly and that the OS takes advantage of the snoop feature. If you are seeing differences in accesses to DMA and non-DMA memory regions then I can only assume your CPU either does not have cache snooping capabilities (check CPU docs) or the capability is not used because it doesn't work (check CPU errata).

Problems with your proposed approach:

1. Do you know when it is time to change the memory region back to non-cacheable?
2. Changing MMU settings for a memory region is not always trivial (is CPU dependent) and I'm not sure an API even exists within your OS for changing such settings.
3. Changing MMU settings for a memory region is risky even when it is possible and such changes must be carefully synchronized with your DMA operation or data corruption is virtually guaranteed.

Given all of these significant problems, I suggest a better approach is to copy the data from the DMA buffer to the `kmalloc()` buffer when you detect the DMA buffer has been updated.

Comment: I have complete control over the timing of the memory modification. Also, I'm sure that the CPU supports snoop (ARM cortex-a9 quad core). Copying is our fallback option, as we have too many processes that will have to do this memcpy to their own virtual memory space. This might be a memory intensive
 procedure...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can implement such logic safely, I'm just looking for the API...

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about your system but what I'm suggesting would require only one copy from the DMA buffer to a `kmalloc` buffer and you then `mmap()` the `kmalloc` buffer rather than the DMA buffer. And if you are certain the cortex-a9 has working snoop architecture, then just use a `kmalloc` buffer as your DMA buffer.

Comment: BTW, if you are looking for the API, you will need to specify an OS and a version of that OS!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - is copying the data to a kmalloc buffer is faster than copying it from user space after the mmap to a regualar malloc'd or memory shared buffer?  as far as I know, it is more or less the same... Copying the data into such buffer is what I'm trying to avoid, as my application require low latency...

Comment: I don't think we are understanding one another. You currently access a shared mmap'd DMA buffer, `dmabuf`, from multiple different apps in user space. This is too slow which is almost certainly due to `dmabuf` being non-cacheable. I'm suggesting that you do not mmap `dmabuf` and instead mmap a kmalloc'd buffer we'll call `kmalbuf`. Since you know when `dmabuf` is updated you can easily copy (one time) from `dmabuf` into `kmalbuf` inside a driver ISR or kernel task. Your user space apps then read from the mmap'd `kmalbuf` which should avoid all apps reading from the non-cached `dmabuf`.

Comment: slowjelj - The one time copy is what I want to avoid. My use case is regarding chunks of 20MB which update 20 times a second. Copying all that data consume too much of my memory's bandwidth.

Comment: By the way - The alternative i'm currently trying is to NOT use DMA_ALLOC_COHERENT, but simply manage this memory by myself, giving the peripheral device a physical pointer, and supplying to the user application a pointer to the same memory without letting the kernel know it is writing via DMA. When I get the signal which means that the memory changed, I'll issue a cache invalidate procedure for the relevant addresses. Can you advice if such solution is possible?

Comment: The use of DMA_ALLOC_COHERENT will work even without a manual cache invalidate *if* cache snooping works properly on your processor. Invalidating any DMA'd memory that is resident in the cache is exactly what snooping does automatically for you. As stated in my original answer, a "DMA buffer" and a plain kmalloc buffer are identical on a system with functional cache snooping (or they *could* be identical). The reason isthat cache snooping detects DMA updates and invalidates any of the DMA memory resident in cache. The result is effectively the same as using a non-cacheable chunk of memory.

Comment: I suggest you proceed with the DMA_ALLOC_COHERENT approach since 20MB being shuffled around multiple times per second is definitely beyond what I expected. Also, testing that snooping works correctly is possible but I suggest checking your processor errata for cache snooping issues. If cache snooping is broke, your manual cache invalidate should work regardless of cache snooping (i.e. you could always do the manual cache invalidate even if snooping works -- it just won't actually do anything if snooping works).